# Calculate $\ln(2)$ using Taylor series and no calculator.

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

How do I have calculate $\ln(2)$ using Taylor series and no calculator?

Comment: Hint, consider the expansion of $\ln(1+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

A faster convergent series is given by $$\log\Big(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\Big)= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$ Use $x=\frac 13$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that 
\begin{equation}
\log(2) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k2^k}
\end{equation}
by integrating both sides of the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1-q} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty q^j
\end{equation}
and then making a suitable choice of $q$. You are still using Taylor series, so you are still following your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for $|x|<1$
$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$
Try to prove that this series is convergent also for $x=1$.